# How to display blocks in the order in which they came to me in the object

Tags: html, handlebars.js

I use https://handlebarsjs.com. 
Here is my template:

```
<div class="container-description">
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <p>
        {{project.descriptions}}
    </p>
    {{#if comment}}
    <div class="comment-container">
        <div class="comment-preview">
            <dev class="message-comment">{{comment.comment}}</dev>
            <div class="comment-author">{{comment.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    <p>
        {{project.subDescriptions}}
    </p>
</div>
```

I get an object:

```
{
    project: [
        "descriptions": "text",
        "name": "text",
        "comment": "text",
        "subDescriptions": "text"
    ]
}
```

It works well.

My problem is that if an object comes in, the fields of which are swapped. For example:

```
{
    project: [
        "descriptions": "text",
        "subDescriptions": "text",
        "name": "text",
        "comment": "text"
    ]
}

or 

{
    project: [
        "descriptions": "text",
        "name": "text",
        "comment": "text"
        "subDescriptions": "text"
    ]
}
```

Then the template should look like this.

```
<div class="container-description">
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <p>
        {{project.descriptions}}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{project.subDescriptions}}
    </p>
    {{#if comment}}
    <div class="comment-container">
        <div class="comment-preview">
            <dev class="message-comment">{{comment.comment}}</dev>
            <div class="comment-author">{{comment.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
</div>

or

<div class="container-description">
    <h2>Description</h2>
    {{#if comment}}
    <div class="comment-container">
        <div class="comment-preview">
            <dev class="message-comment">{{comment.comment}}</dev>
            <div class="comment-author">{{comment.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    <p>
        {{project.descriptions}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Or something like that.

How do I display the blocks in my template in the order in which they came to me in the object?

Comment: The order of the **key: value** pairs in your object should not have an effect on how the data is displayed in your UI. You can define your own order as you did up in your handlebars template and pick and choose what fields you want displayed.

Comment: @Manu How can I do this? How to solve my problem so that the blocks are displayed in a different order?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    project: [
        "descriptions": "text",
        "name": "text",
        "comment": "text"
        "subDescriptions": "text",
        "subDescriptions": "text",
        "subDescriptions": "text",
    ]
}
```

The above is not valid JSON (**subDescriptions** are duplicate keys and everything should be unique). If you want multiple descriptions you can have something like

```
{
    "project": [
      {
        "descriptions": "text",
        "name": "text",
        "comment": "text",
        "subdescriptions": 
          [
            { "text1" },
            { "text2" },
            { "text3" }
          ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Then you can parse the above with handlebars

```
{{#each subdescriptions}}
    <p>{{this}}</p>
{{/each}}
```